# SMTP authentication for Mercury Mail Server (Xampp) on Windows

Tags: xampp, mail-server

I want to use Mercury Mail as a mail server in a local network. I managed to set up everything and I am able to send mails from one client to another in this local network via the Mercury Mail server (part of Xampp) on Windows 7. The whole environment is set up locally, i.e. communication is only between local users and not with the outside world (internet).

What I want now: When a local user sends a mail to another local user, I want them to SMTP authenticate first. From Mercury Mail Admin Panel SMTP Server, I don't see such option. Could you point me to the documentation or guide me on how to do it? Thanks a lot.

[image: Mercury SMTP Server configuration]